# Getting plain text from json API

Tags: php, json, xslt

So I have this api: `http://85.17.32.4:8707/status-json.xsl`

And I want to extract a few things from it, so I started off really basic:

```
 <?php echo json_decode('http://85.17.32.4:8707/status-json.xsl');
```

It gave absolutely no result. Next try:

```
<?php
$var = json_decode('http://85.17.32.4:8707/status-json.xsl');
var_dump($var);
```

It just retourned `NULL`.

Then I tried making a cURL function:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://85.17.32.4:8707/status-json.xsl';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

This also returned NULL. Do I have any further options?

Thanks.

Comment: That "JSON" is totally invalid. According to an online parser, there are at least 8 errors inside.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid json string at all. Make sure the API is returning a valid json. The brackets are wrong and you have unescaped values such as the quote in `Guns N' Roses` which could later lead to problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do have further options: check [`json_last_error_msg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) and see whether there was an issue with the json decoding:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);

# check if there has been an error decoding:
if (! isset($json)) {
    echo "Decoding error: " . json_last_error_msg() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Decoding error: Syntax error
```

i.e. there is a syntax error in the JSON. You need to tell the JSON provider that they are not providing valid JSON.